# Как развернуть yii2 приложение одной консольной командой?

Tags: yii2

Собственно вопрос в заголовке: можно ли развернуть yii2 одной консольной командой? Я понимаю, что нужно как минимум запустить composer install, а далее php yii migrate. Можно ли это как-нибудь совместить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться в Unix-подобных системах оператором && для соединения команд. 
к примеру:

```
composer install && php yii migrate --migrationPath=@yii/rbac/migrations && php yii migrate
```

Здесь у меня:

1. установка зависимостей
2. запуск миграций rbac
3. запуск остальных миграций